# Squash arbitrary commits in a remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, server, gitlab

I am a bit of a noob with Git and was tasked to clean up the history of a feature I developed recently. I have a similar setup to this fellow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774801/git-how-to-squash-several-commits-that-have-been-pushed-to-a-remote-repo). I also kind of want to accomplish the same thing, but I want to squash to specific commits. For example, if my commits are ***commit1, commit2, ..., commitN***, I want to make it so that ***commit1, commit2, ...*** are squashed to ***commitX***; ***commitX+1, commitX+2, ...*** are squashed to ***commitY***; etc.

I understand that this is possible with the command

```
git rebase -i origin/*branch_name*
```

but the problem is that when I run that command, I get this:

```
noop

# Rebase a112005..a112005 onto a112005 (1 command(s))
...
```

As far as I understand, the last and the first commits should be displayed here, but it only sees the last commit. When I try to run pick or squash with any other commit it says:

```
error: could not apply *commit hash*... *commit message*
```

which obviously means that it finds the commit since it knows its message, but for some reason, it doesn't even see it as editable. Anybody have any idea how I can fix this? Also if someone recommends either a better terminal-based synchronization system for my setup or a better way of organizing my stuff, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do anything on a remote-tracking branch.  In fact, you cannot be "on" a remote-tracking branch in the first place.  (The `git checkout` command is the one that puts you "on a branch", as `git status` shows; but it will not put you on a remote-tracking branch, only on a local branch.)

In general, to make something happen in a Git repository, you must make it happen in *your* Git repository, using *your* branch-names.

When you want something to happen in someone *else*'s Git repository (such as the one on `origin`), the way you do this is to first, get everything set up in *your* repository, then use `git push` to *ask* them to take your work into *their* repository and set one of *their* branch names to match.

If you ask them—the other Git that controls that other repository—to set their *`branch-name`* to point to some specific commit,<sup>1</sup> *and* they agree, *then*, at that point, *your* Git will set your `origin/branch-name` to point to that same commit, since *their* Git has told yours that, yes, it is now using that particular commit for that particular branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>They need to *have* that commit, but your `git push` will give it to them first, if they don't already have it.  That's how `git push` works.  First, it hands over the set of objects that you have that they don't that they need in order to accept your requests; then, it hands over a series of requests: "Please set branch *B1* to commit *1234567...*, and/or branch *B2* to commit *89abcde...*, and/or set tag *T* to ...".  Their Git obeys none, some, or all of these requests, sending either "ok" or "no, and here's why" responses for each one.

Comment: Okay, so in that case I should use "git rebase -i *branch_name*" without origin, edit what I want and then use "git push" to save to the remote branch, right?

Comment: Yes: but you will have to force the push (with or without the "lease" option) to get them to accept it. Read other answers on this to see where the issues are with that. They all flow from the fact that you have to get your Git repo in sync with theirs before you start, and it could get *out* of sync again while you work.